# div with hero image, html form and text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a div with a back ground image, a signup form at the right end and a div with h1 tags on the left.

HTML code:

```
<html>
<title> GoToMy PC </title>
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blah.css" /> </head>
<body>


<section class="imageform">

<div>
<h1> Heading text goes here </h1>
<h2> Sub text goes here </h2> 
</div>

 <form class="signup_form">


<label class="holder-text"> Your Name </label><br/><input class="field_height" type="text"   name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">  <input class="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"><br/>
<label class="holder-text">E-mail address</label><br/><input class="field_width_height" type="email" name="user_email"> <br/>
<label class="holder-text">Password</label><br/><input class="field_width_height" type="password" name="password" ><br/>
<label class="holder-text"> At least 8 characters with both letters and numbers </label><br/>


 </form>

</section>  <!--End of imageform section -->
```

The form show up in the page but its not floating right, the div with h1 tags is at the bottom of the page and back ground image shows up only when screen width is made too small.

Any help in fixing this is much appreciated.

JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/fwkqos0c/

Comment: What should it look like? Is there a mockup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code. you are implementing a lot of junk css. such as `height: auto` there is no need to call it. 
you were also calling margins for positioning instead of a float.

I added a class to the div to keep things easy to read of title:

```
.title{
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 color: white;
}
```

Look through the code let me know if you have any questions of why i used something in particular.

Also the background could be easily done with a gradient instead of an image.

http://jsfiddle.net/fwkqos0c/2/

Comment: Thank you! Now that I compare your edit and my original code, I realize how convoluted my code was. I need to use an image for back ground ( I couldn't upload the same pic here as it'd disclose my employer's identity).

Comment: It works perfectly fine in desktop mode. I am building a responsive site. when I scale the browser size down, even before media queries can kick in, the sign up slides down. Is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: Yes, check the code i have the width of the title at 50% you can reduce that to 30% or so the best way to learn is to play around with your code